# Difficulty with activesupport when attempting to deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2, activesupport

I have a rails application that I am trying to deploy onto the internet. I have setup a server on the Amazon EC2 cloud, that I know works because I have deployed another site to the same machine.

When I try to run this new application either through 'rails console' or when running 'rake db:seed' or just by trying to browse to the application, rails crashes saying it cannot find activiesupport:

> /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/big_decimal/conversions.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- bigdecimal (LoadError)

My Rails version is 3.2.2 and I'm using ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30) [x86_64-linux]. My database is MongoDB which I access through Mongoid. And I'm using Passenger and Apache as a server.

Is there any configuration step or something like that that I have missed?

P.S. I know I shouldn't be using ec2-user, I'm still experimenting. And also, I've never had much luck with RVM.

Comment: `I'm using ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30) [x86_64-linux]`   `/home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/` the app wants to use 1.9.1 gems it seems, are you sure you're running on 1.9.3?

Comment: I quoted the result of `ruby -v`. How can I get the gems to be the same version as ruby itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I encountered the same problem with Rails 3.2.3 and Ruby 1.9.3p0 on my Amazon EC2 instance, where Ruby had been installed with the ruby19 yum package. In my case, the problem seemed to be that I had installed the bigdecimal gem manually using the gem command instead of using Bundler. To fix the problem, I uninstalled the gem manually, added the line

gem 'bigdecimal'

to my application's Gemfile, and re-ran bundle install. This reinstalled the gem and then my application was able to load it successfully.

My gems are also installed in ~/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/, even though I am running Ruby 1.9.3p0. This does not appear to be a problem.

Comment: I had to do the same for `minitest-spec-rails`. And now I'm up and running.